# Apply vectorised function to Cartesian product of two ranges in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, cartesian-product

I am kind of new to pytorch, and have a very simple question. Let's say we have a scalar function `f()`:

```
def f(x,y):
    return np.cos(x)+y
```

What I want to do is use the GPU to generate all pairs of data-points from two ranges `x` and `y`. For simple case, take `x=y=[0,1,2]`.

Can I do that without changing the function? If not, how would you change the function?

Comment: What does it mean for `f` to be "non-tensor"? Does it mean that its value is scalar? Is its domain still non-scalar? What does it mean for a GPU to "generate the data"? What is "the range" of `x` and `y`? Does "changing the function" refer to changing the function in a mathematical sense or in a Python sense?

Comment: sorry for unclear statement, f will be just scalar, and generate data means that (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2) scan those parameter prallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the Cartesian product of the values before applying your function to their first and second elements:

```py
x = y = torch.tensor([0,1,2])

pairs = torch.cartesian_prod(x,y)
# tensor([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], ​[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]])

x_, y_ = pairs[:,0], pairs[:,1]
f(x_,y_)
```